# std::unordered_map::count is not working in my code

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

I have a doubt with the solution of this question which is stated below -

Given an arbitrary ransom note string and another string containing letters from all the magazines, write a function that will return true if the ransom note can be constructed from the magazines ; otherwise, it will return false.

Each letter in the magazine string can only be used once in your ransom note.
Strings["aa", "ab"] should return false and strings["aa", "aab"] should return true according to question.

Here is the code which I have attempted in the first place and I'm not getting a required output as mentioned above.

```
        unordered_map<char,int>umap;

        for(char m:magazine)
        {
            umap[m]++;
        }

        for(char r:ransomNote)
        { 
            if(umap.count(r)<=1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else{
                umap[r]--;
            }


        }
       return true; 
    }
```

In the above code, I have used `umap.count(r)<=1` to return false if there is no key present.
For the strings ["aa","aab"], it is returning true but for strings ["aa","ab"], it is also returning true but it should return false.
Then I used another way to solve this problem by using just `umap[r]<=0` in the place of `umap.count(r)<=1` and it is working just fine and else all code is same.

```
bool canConstruct(string ransomNote, string magazine) {

        unordered_map<char,int>umap;

        for(char m:magazine)
        {
            umap[m]++;
        }

        for(char r:ransomNote)
        { 
            if(umap[r]<=0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else{
                umap[r]--;
            }


        }
       return true; 
    }
```

I'm not able to get what i'm missing in the if condition of first code. Can anyone help me to state what I'm doing wrong in first code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure because I can't follow your explanation, but `umap.count(r)<=1` will always be true for any value of `r`. `unordered_map::count` always returns 0 or 1. Maybe you meant `if (umap.count(r) == 0)` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: *"I have used `umap.count(r)<=1` to return false if there is no key present."* - No, you didn't. `umap.count(r)<=1` is always true. Think about why. Either `r` is there(1), or it isn't (0). Both are <= 1. You should be using `umap.count(r) == 0`, and in fact, should really just use an iterator so as not to have to perform the search twice (once for the lookup; once for the decrement).

Comment: @john @WhozCraig I've tried using `if (umap.count(r) == 0)` but it is still returning true. It should return false now. I'm not getting what is wrong with this logic.

Comment: `umap.count` only returns 0 if the key doesn't exist. If the key exists but the value is 0 (when you used up all copies of one character), it will still return 1. You seem to have a misunderstanding of what the `count` function does.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Thanks for the explanation, I understood why `if (umap.count(r) == 0)` was returning true instead of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unordered_map::count` returns the number of items with specified key.

As you don't use `multi_map` version, you only have 0 or 1.

Associated value doesn't change presence of key in map.

To use `count`, you should remove key when value reaches 0:

```
for (char r : ransomNote) {
    if (umap.count(r) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (--umap[r] == 0) {
            umap.erase(r);
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it actually worked for me and I understood the logic behind it.